# Include jsp возращаемые параметры

Tags: java, include, jsp

Здравствуйте, я подключаю файл 
...
<jsp:include page="cookieuser" />
...
там происходит какое-то действие и нужно получить обратно значение, как это сделать?)

Answer (score 1):

Наверное так:

```
<c:set var="name" scope="request" value="val" />
```

У них requestScope должен разделятся, а принять так:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.name}" />
```

Ну или всё тоже, только через скриптлеты.

```
<%request.setAttribute("naem", "val");%>
```

и

```
<%=request.getAttribute("name")%>
```